# http live streaming in centOS implementaion

Tags: http-live-streaming

I need to setup http live streaming in centOS , Please any one help in this with step by step configuration ?

I did lot of go-ogling but i dint find the proper solution . Every one tell about using ff mpeg we can achieve this . But not proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install a webserver with webdav support.apache with webdav modules activated will do it. the webdav_fs module expands the apache with user rights to write on a predefined directory.so, you create this directory first (eg /opt/webdav/hls/path2stream) and chmod and chown this directory to eg user and group "apache".then, you will have to edit httpd.conf to edit the server name according to the uname convention.finally, you can log the PUT commands by the encoder and the GET commands from the player in the apache log directory (/var/log/httpd/..access_log.

greez, nico